# What is the limit of the sequence? (Bryant)

Tags: sequences-and-series

$1 \leq x_n < 2$

$x_1=1$

$x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}}{2}+\frac{1}{[x_{n-1}]}$

My proof would be:

$(x_n)$ is increasing and bounded above, thus convergent.

Assume that $\lim(x_{n+1})=\lim(x_n)=x$

$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}+\frac{1}{[x_n]}$

Since $1 \leq x_n < 2$ it holds that $\frac{1}{[x_n]}=1$

Therefore, $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}+1$

$\lim(x_{n+1})=\frac{x}{2}+1=x$ so $x=2$

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

With an induction you see that
$$
x_n = \frac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}},
$$
and so the sequence converges to 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you define
$$
x_1=1,\qquad x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}+\frac{1}{\lfloor x_n\rfloor}
$$
you have to *prove* that $1\le x_n<2$ to begin with.

You also state without proof that the sequence is increasing, which is not completely obvious.

The base step for the induction is obvious. If $1\le x_n<2$, then $\lfloor x_n\rfloor=1$ and therefore
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+2}{2}
$$
and $3\le x_n+2<4$, forcing $3/2\le x_{n+1}<2$.

Also
$$
x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{x_n+2}{2}-x_n=\frac{2-x_n}{2}>0
$$
so the sequence is increasing (and bounded). Hence it converges to $l$ and
$$
l=\frac{l+2}{2}
$$